# Learn Python 2 Codeacademy, "A Day at the Supermarket"

Tags: python

I am working on a basic python 2 tutorial and the following code was presented as the correct answer:

```
total=0

prices = {
  "banana" : 4,
  "apple"  : 2,
  "orange" : 1.5,
  "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
  "banana" : 6,
  "apple"  : 0,
  "orange" : 32,
  "pear"   : 15,
}

for fruit in prices:

    print fruit

    print "price: %s" % prices[fruit]

    print "stock: %s" % stock[fruit]

    total =  total + prices[fruit] * stock[fruit]  # pretend this line is bolded

    print total

     #prints sum of total (0) and prices multiplied by stock (117). Equals 117.
```

What I want to know is why the following code below replacing the 2nd to last line (bolded in the block above) returns zero instead of also returning 117.

```
total2 = prices[fruit] * stock[fruit]
print total2 + total

 #should be total2(117) plus total(0). Equals 117
```

Can anyone walk me through why python logic treats the variable "total" differently from "total2". I suspect it has something to do with the fact that one of the totals of price multiplied by stock is equal to zero and zero times a anything is zero. In my mind, I should be able to create a whole new variable (total2) containing the results of prices X stock and then add it to total. I apologize for the lack of indentation in the code, can't seem to get the code to post exactly as formatted.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might have gotten a downvote on this question because it appears (based on your question title) that you are asking for help on a "homework" question, which is traditionally something SO does not like to provide. Since your question actually asks something more fundemental, consider editing the title to your question and making what you're really asking (how different variables work "under the hood") clear at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the first snippet and the second snippet is that, in the second snippet, you never assign anything to `total`, only to `total2`.

```
total2 = prices[fruit] * stock[fruit]
print total2 + total
```

Note that, while you set `total2` to a specific value, you haven't told python to set `total` to any other value. *Printing the sum of `total` and `total2` doesn't change the value of either of those things.*

So, you just need to properly add `total2` to `total`, and actually put the result in `total` instead of just printing it:

```
total = total + total2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was thinking that since we set the value of variable "total" to 0 in the beginning, and then set variable "total2" to 117, printing "total" (0) plus "total2" (117) would print 117.